# Restrict LAG to specific row condition

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, lag

I am using the following query to return the percentage difference between this month and last month for a given Site ID.

```
SELECT 
reporting_month,
total_revenue,
invoice_count,
--total_revenue_prev,
--invoice_count_prev,
ROUND(SAFE_DIVIDE(total_revenue,total_revenue_prev)-1,4) AS actual_growth,
site_name
FROM (

SELECT DATE_TRUNC(table.date, MONTH) AS reporting_month,
        ROUND(SUM(table.revenue),2) AS total_revenue, 
        COUNT(*) AS invoice_count,
        ROUND(IFNULL(
           LAG(SUM(table.revenue)) OVER (ORDER BY MIN(DATE_TRUNC(table.date, MONTH))) ,
           0),2) AS total_revenue_prev,
        IFNULL(
           LAG(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY MIN(DATE_TRUNC(table.date, MONTH))) ,
           0) AS invoice_count_prev,
        tbl_sites.name AS site_name
FROM table
LEFT JOIN tbl_sites ON tbl_sites.id = table.site
WHERE table.site = '123'
GROUP BY site_name, reporting_month
ORDER BY reporting_month
)
```

This is working correctly, printing:

| reporting_month | total revenue | invoice_count | actual_growth | site_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-11-01 00:00:00 UTC | 100.00 | 10 | 0.571 | SiteNameString |
| 2020-12-01 00:00:00 UTC | 125.00 | 7 | 0.2500 | SiteNameString |

However I would like to be able to run the same query for all sites. When I remove `WHERE table.site = '123'` from the subquery, I assume it is the use of `LAG` that is making the numbers report incorrectly. Is there a way to restrict the LAG to the 'current' row site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add a PARTITION BY clause in your LAG statement to define a *window function* :

```
LAG(SUM(table.revenue)) OVER (PARTITION BY table.site ORDER BY table.date, MONTH)
```

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/analytic-function-concepts#def_window_spec) is the related BigQuery documentation page

"PARTITION BY: Breaks up the input rows into separate partitions, over which the analytic function is independently evaluated."